# how to return all fields in rest practical Request tracker REST API 2.0

Tags: rest

In Best practical request tracker api there is `fields` property to specify fields which should be returned. For example:
https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST

```
mypage.com/REST/1.0/search/ticket?
query=format=l&fields=Subject,Status,Priority,CF.{Category}
```

How to do it in 2.0? There is nothing in documentation regarding that so I think they didn't change anything. However whatever I do it only returns only id, and type properties.

mypage.com/REST/2.0/tickets/query=format=l&fields=Subject,Status,Priority,CF.
    {Category}&status:new

Comment: I have the same issue. There also seems to be a lack of "orderby", which makes their nice paging not quite so nice.